# From $\|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos(\theta)$ to the dot product definition

Tags: vectors

I know that $\vec u\cdot \vec v\overset{\text{def}}{=}u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\cdots+u_nv_n$ and I know the proof of $\vec u\cdot \vec v=\|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos(\theta)$. $$$$my question is, if I'm redefining the dot product to be $\vec u\cdot \vec v\overset{\text{def}}{=}\|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos(\theta)$ can I proof that $\vec u\cdot \vec v=u_1v_1+u_2v_2+\cdots+u_nv_n$ is true?

## Edit

Some people said I need to redefine $\|\vec u\|$, so I'm defining it with pythagorean theorem so it's value won't change

Comment: How do you define $\|u\|$?  Normally $\|u\|$ is defined as $\sqrt{u\cdot u}$, but if you are changing the definition of $\cdot$ then you run into the problem of needing to know how to compute the dot product in order to compute the dot product.

Comment: The problem lies in the definition of angle

Comment: @JMoravitz I can definite it with pythagorean theorem and get the same result, I'll add it to the post

Comment: @edm. Good point. For $a\ne 0\ne b$ you can define $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\;(\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2-\|u-v\|^2)(2\|a\|\cdot \|b\|)^{-1}\;)$ (Cosine Law), once you have shown that this will not involve  $\cos^{-1}x$ for some $x\not \in [-1,1].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align} \text{using Cosine Law}& \\  \|\vec u-\vec v\|^2=&\|\vec u\|^2+\|\vec v\|^2-2\|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos\theta\\ \|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos\theta=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\|\vec u\|^2+\|\vec v\|^2-\|\vec u-\vec v\|^2\right)\\\text{so: }&\\ \vec u \cdot \vec v =& \|\vec u\|\|\vec v\|\cos \theta \\ =& \frac{1}{2}\left(\|\vec u\|^2 + \|\vec v\|^2 - \|\vec u-\vec v\|^2\right) \\ &\text{i defined $\|\vec u\|$ with pythagorean theorem so:}\\=&\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n (u_i-v_i)^2\right) \\ =&\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n \left(u_i^2+v_i^2-2u_iv_i\right)\right)\\ =&\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\left( u_i^2 + v_i^2 - \left(u_i^2+v_i^2-2u_iv_i\right)\right)\right)\\ =& \sum_{i=1}^n u_iv_i \end{align}

thanks to the comments that helped

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy Schwartz there exists a unique $\theta$ such that for a given inner product,

$$ \langle u,v \rangle  = \| u \| \|v\| \cos(\theta)$$

is well defined where $\|u\| = \langle u,u \rangle$. The dot product is a particular inner product so yes the result follows immediately if you know these facts.

Comment: [$\color{red}{\text{How about this?}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923330/dot-product-and-its-representation-as-sum/1957425#1957425)

Comment: Steven. Very nice!